# retrieved value error jstl

Tags: jsp, jstl

This is the value retrieved from database :

```
<select id="approve" name="approval">
    <option value="0">-- Please select one --</option>
    <option value=Tan Ah Kau >Tan Ah Kau</option>
</select>
```

Here is my JSP :

```
<select id="approve" name="approval">
    <option value="0">-- Please select one --</option>
    <c:forEach items="${arrSta}" var="arrSta">
    <option value=${arrSta.name} ${arrSta.name == selectedTutor ? 'selected' : ''}>${arrSta.name}</option>
     </c:forEach>
</select>
```

The problem now is when I want to get the value from dropdownlist, the value supposed I get is Tan Ah Kau but now I only can get Tan .

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<option value="Tan Ah Kau">Tan Ah Kau</option>

<option value="${arrSta.name}"> ${arrSta.name}</option>
```

use quotes for value.